# Django, apidoc js What to add in a PUT method?

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

I have read the apidoc.js documentation and i have a dilemma. I don't exactly know the difference between @apiParam and @apiSucces, the documentation doesn't explain properly what they really do. For example i have a get and a put with these parameters in the get:

I am using apidoc in django and this is my view:

```
class LocationView(APIView):

    """
    @api {get} /locations/:id/ Location id - details
    @apiName GetLocation
    @apiGroup Locations

    @apiParam {integer} [id] Location id.
    @apiParam {string} [name] Location name.
    @apiParam {object} [company] Company name.
    @apiParam {string} [website] Location website.

    @apiSuccess {object[]} results List with location details
    """
    serializer_class = LocationSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Location.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Location.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk):
        serializer = LocationSerializer(self.get_object(pk))
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk):
        location = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = LocationSerializer(location, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk):
        location = self.get_object(pk)
        location.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

I want to create the put apidoc. What do i have to write in it for modifying? Do i have to write every parameter again? or use apiSuccess? An example would be great.

Comment: Nothing, PUT method is correct and also returning proper response.

Comment: no, no, i mean in the api doc, i want to create the apidoc for put and delete aswell and i don't know how really.. i edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the difference between `@apiSuccess` and `@apiParam` is that:

**`@apiSuccess`**: describes the fields and their data types for a successful response;

**`@apiParam`**: describes the fields and their data types for a path input parameter;

To be more exact, you use `apiSuccess` to describe what the response will look like (the **successful** response), and you use `apiParam` to describe what the request for that response should contain

I find [this blog](https://blog.jscrambler.com/documenting-apis-using-apidoc-js/) providing a good example of how to use `apidoc`. You just need to adapt it to your django app